# Condition for Next Clause While Alter Materialized View

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-06502

I am trying to refresh a materialized view for some days and between some hours and my code:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW M_MVIEW
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH TO_DATE('11-07-2014 10:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                        NEXT (CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'D','NLS_SORT = XTURKISH') = 5) AND (SYSDATE BETWEEN (TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-07-2014 21:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + 20/24) AND (TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-07-2014 21:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + 31/24)) THEN TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('10-07-2014 21:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'PAZARTESİ')) + 7/24
                                   WHEN (SYSDATE BETWEEN (TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-07-2014 21:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + 20/24) AND (TRUNC(TO_DATE('10-07-2014 21:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) + 31/24)) THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 31/24
                                   ELSE SYSDATE + 2/24 END)
```

But I am getting error; `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s`
I tried to solve my problem but I couldn't. Does anyone have any idea for my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: For NEXT clause in a materialized view you can write CASE statement but it acceptes only two condition. My suggestion is that simplify your condition if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NEXT clause in a materialized view you can write CASE statement but it acceptes only two condition (it should be very simple like `case when x=x then aa else bb end`). My suggestion is that simplify your condition if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The *real* error message is somewhat more telling:

```
ORA-12899: Value too large for column "SYS"."JOB$"."INTERVAL#" (actual: 595, maximum: 200)
```

so it seems you're trying to set a value for `INTERVAL` that is too large.

Personally, I never use the `START WITH / NEXT` for Materialized Views. I prefer creating a `DBMS_SCHEDULER` job for the refresh because

- the syntax for specifying the run dates is much, much better
- you get a history of your refreshes from `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG`
- you can enable/disable the refresh at will

Comment: Thank you Frank for your response. I solved my problem by simlify my condition.

Comment: @yagmurdursun Then I'd suggest you post your solution as an answer, so people encountering the same problem know how to solve it.